# How to create peer to peer communication among four systems using java network programming

Tags: java, networking

Bascially I want to establish a network as follows

1.Server

Other 3 clients.Using java.net package's Socket and Server socket class I made the Server program  and client programs.There is a two way communication link between Server and Clients.
upto here all cool, but my intention is to create a communication link between these clients also.But how can i do this.
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: There is lots of ways of doing that. Too many to mention. I would start with what you believe is simplest to implement.

Comment: YES can u mention a few.

Comment: You can use raw TCP with plain IO or NIO, JMS, REST over HTTP, SSH, UDP, SCTP, MPI, MPJ.  Libraries which support this are Messaging Servers, Grid systems, Distributed Caches....

Comment: I just want to with the java network programming.I did not get your idea.Can You elaborate.

Comment: It is a very complex subject with a wide range of options.  Without more information, I suggest you do plain IO Sockets, unless there is a communication technology you are more familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Peer to Peer connections using UDP or TCP hole punching.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can re-invent the wheel, i.e. implement what you mentioned: server that opens server socket and waits for connections from clients, clients that somehow know where the server is and connect to it etc, I'd suggest you to use higher level tools.

The choice depends on the nature of your application.

1. Should your server run in container?
2. Should your connection be established in local network or over internet?
3. How complicated is your data that travels over network?
4. Do you have special performance requirements?

etc, etc.

So, you can use on of possible messaging (JMS, Kafka etc) or grid (Hazelcast, GigaSpaces) etc, etc.

Try to prepare answers to my questions. Try to find other questions and answer them. Then ask more specific questions here.

Comment: Yes I have programmed a Server that opens Socket and clients get connected to it.But I want a communication link between clients using java network programming.I am a newbie to java world and I am a student.

Comment: @Intriguing That sounds like what you are doing.  What do you mean by network programming you are not doing already?

Answer (score 0):

First, you said 1 server and 3 clients, so that is client/server, and not peer-to-peer. My suggestion is to use either socket programming (either java.net.ServerSocket on the server, or a framework around it like Netty or 0MQ), or to use something higher level like HTTP and REST. Once clients connect to the server, just have the server send the new client all the info about the old clients & vice-versa, and they can connect directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to start reading this [Socket programming tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) from Java doc, for following reasons:

1. No prior knowledge of server-client programming is necessary to follow the tutorial, only basic familiarity of I/O operation will be helpful.
2. The tutorial starts by defining socket, then describing set-up for Client and then starts talking about Server side handling.
3. After describing single server, single client set-up, it touches single server-multiple client communication, and, with a bonus of providing source codes for everything you need to play with.

My recommendation would be to download all the source codes first, then load them in your favorite IDEs and start reading the tutorial and tracing the code simultaneously. I find this process really useful.